# How to simplify this composition function $g(x)=\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{f \circ f \circ f \circ f\circ f \circ \cdots\circ f}}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{(1+\sin^n(x))^{1/n}}$ and $g(x)=\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{f \circ f \circ f \circ f\circ f \circ \cdots\circ f}}(x)$. Where $\circ$ represents function composition.

Show that $g(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{(1+n\sin^n(x))^{1/n}}$.

I cant spot any pattern in the composition function. Each time it's becoming more complicated. Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wait, what is the $n$ in the $f$ function compared to the $n$ number of compositions? Is it a different $n$? Should it be there at all?

Comment: No no its the same n...@HowDoIMath

Comment: @Sanchayan: what is $\sin^2(x)$: Is it $\sin(\sin(x))$ or $\sin(x) \cdot \sin(x)$

Comment: @miracle173 the second one...

Comment: It looks scary! :D have your tried using complex exponential?

Comment: @H.R. I dont know that...

Comment: I think that the first step is to simplify $f(x)$ in some manner! :)

Comment: You say :-) how to?

Comment: @Sanchayan: did you check this numerically?

Comment: Have you checked the result numerically? Unless I made some error, it seems to be false even for $n = 2$ and $x = \pi/3$. – Where does the formula come from? Why do you think that it is true?

Comment: It's clearly false for $n=1$.

Comment: As you guys are saying so...i believe that the question in my book is itself wrong or a misprint then. @MartinR should I post a picture ?

Comment: @MartinR I can confirm with your counter example: [Wolfram Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi%2F3%29%2F%28+1+%2B+sin%5E2%28pi%2F3%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C+sin%28sqrt%283%2F7%29%29%2F%28+1+%2B+sin%5E2%28sqrt%283%2F7%29%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C+sin%28pi%2F3%29%2F%28+1+%2B+2sin%5E2%28pi%2F3%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29)

Comment: I agree with @Martin R (for $n=2$ and $x=\pi/4$). Do you forget an ${\rm Arcsin}$ ?. If $\varphi(x)={\rm Arcsin}(f(x))$, the result is true (composition of $h(u)=\frac{u}{(1+u^n)^{1/n}}$ $k$-times with itself gives $\frac{u}{(1+ku^n)^{1/n}}$ by induction)

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, misprints do occasionally happen.  A picture might help.

Comment: @BarryCipra I may be mistaken, but it seems to me it's clearly *true* when $n=1$... $f(x) = \sin x / (1 + \sin^1 x)^1 = \sin x / (1 + 1 \cdot \sin^1 x)^1$...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The sarcasm was lost on you, it seems. Barry was clearly joking.

Comment: ...am I surrounded by 14 year olds? I don't see how it's clearly a joke, it's very possible for someone to make a mistake (off-by-one error, something like that) and think it's false.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, you are quite right, I made a mistake.

Comment: @Axoren, no, I was clearly just being stupid.  Unlike misprints, which only occasionally happen, misteaks, at least for me, are frequent.

Answer (score 2):

Let an $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ be fixed, and consider  the function
$$F(y):={y\over(1+y^n)^{1/n}}\qquad(y\geq0)\ .$$
This $F$ can be considered as composition
$$F={\rm root}_n\circ T\circ {\rm pow}_n\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby 
$${\rm root}_n(t):=t^{1/n},\quad {\rm pow}_n(t):=t^n\qquad(t\geq0)\ ,$$
and
$$T(t):={t\over 1+t}\ .$$
It is well known, and easily verified by induction that
$$T^{\circ n}(t)={t\over 1 +n\> t}\ .$$
As ${\rm pow}_n\circ {\rm root}_n={\rm id}_{{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}}$ we therefore obtain from $(1)$ that
$$F^{\circ n}={\rm root}_n\circ T^n\circ{\rm pow}_n\ ,$$
or
$$F^{\circ n}(y)=\left({y^n\over 1+ n y^n}\right)^{1/n}={y\over(1+n y^n)^{1/n}}\qquad(y\geq0)\ .$$
Putting $y:=\sin x$ here (assuming $\sin x\geq0$) we therefore have
$$F^{\circ n}(\sin x)={\sin x\over(1+n \sin^n x)^{1/n}}\ .\tag{2}$$
This looks promising, but is not what you wanted: Your $f$ is defined by $f=F\circ\sin$,
but from this it does not follow that
$$f^{\circ n}=F^{\circ n}\circ\sin\ .$$
Instead one has, e.g.,
$$f^{\circ3}=F\circ\sin\circ F\circ\sin \circ F\circ\sin\ .$$
The relation $(2)$ therefore captures what can be saved from the hoped for identity.

Comment: I didnt get you..why are you saying that relation (2) is not same as the relation which i wanted in the question?